# What is the maximum number of Ibecons that a mobile/tablet device can handle

Tags: android, estimote

I have a scenario in which there are beacon bands in hands of the people. The Devices will have to keep entry exit track of all the bands. What can be the maximum number of bands which could be used in which the device could give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on the device. We did a test with iPhone 5C and iPhone 6 Plus. The former was capable of keeping of track of about 100 Bluetooth peripherals (like beacons), the latter--about 300. Since most Android devices have less processing power than iPhones, it's probably safe to err on the lower bound.

Comment: I saw this video. In this he's trying to find out the position of the mobile phone in a closed room with 3 beacons. And it doesn't work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMWEl6GBGqk